# ASP NET Core Insert Model With Related Data

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Model as Below:

```
class ModelA {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set;}
    ICollection<ModelB> TaskList { get; set; }
}

class ModelB {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public int ModelAID { get; set; }
    public ModelA Person { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I use the following code to Add a new row to ModelA with a list of rows ModelB:

```
IEnumerale<ModelB> BList = ....;
ModelA row = new ModelA() { PersonName = 'John' };
foreach (bRow in BList) {
    row.TaskList.add(bRow);
}
```

From the above code, I got an error of "row.TaskList.add(bRow)" line that the error messages say cannot add row into null object.

I just want to ask is it a incorrect way to create a new row with related data?  How can I complete the task without error?  I don't want to split the process into 2 step, first create a row of ModelA then insert the list of ModelB by different method.

Thank you!

Wilson

Comment: add a constructor to ModelA.  in the constructor initialize the collection property `TaskList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid the exception change your class a little...

```
class ModelA {

    public ModelA()
    {
        TaskList = new Collection<ModelB>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set;}
    ICollection<ModelB> TaskList { get; set; }
}
```